# Jquery datatable with checkbox in header and in row:select all checkbox not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using `Jquery Datatable`. I want to have a first column with header and rows with a checkbox and should toggle the selection of header checkbox with remaining row's checkboxes. I have below implementation.

Datatable attribute

```
  "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectall' onclick='toggleChecks(this);' ></input>", "mDataProp": null, "sWidth": "20px", "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' ></input>", "bSortable": false },null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

Datatable row

```
<td><input type="checkbox' class="case"></input></td>
```

Javascript function

```
  function toggleChecks(obj)
    {
        $('.case').prop('checked', obj.checked);
    }
```

This is worked fine when i am on single page. But when I do the paging then checkboxes remain unchecked for other page. How to achieve this for behaving consistently for all checkboxes. Please assist.

Comment: Hi, did you make a workaround for this?

Comment: why dont you toggle checkboxes inside $('#selectall').change(function(){});. I have done like this in couple of tables.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something like,

```
$('#selectall').change(function() {
                        var isSelected = $(this).is(':checked');
                        if(isSelected){
                            $('.case').prop('checked', true);   
                        }else{
                            $('.case').prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    });
```

on document ready.

Comment: The function could be reduced to one line like this: `$('.case').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function fnDrawCallback to update there the table when the page changes.

You can check in this function the value of the header checkbox and update the new rows checkboxes.

You can also add a boolean value to your objects in the model, and change that value when you check or uncheck. If you access to the model you can modify the values of all your elements, not only the rendered ones. Then, when you load your cells you represent that true/false with the checkbox. This is the most consistent approach, but probably will involve much more work to get a good syncro between the model and the view.

Answer (score 0):

guys,

had a similar problem that needed quick solution.

Made a workaround for this problem, might help somebody:

As I dynamically feed the table some data:

```
oTable1.fnAddData
([
    "<span id='" + any_obj.id + "' style='display:block; width: 10px;'><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' /></span>",
    title, 
    modified, 
    version
] );
```

Notice the span for the checkbox. This obviously stays hidden and can be accessed easily.