# JQuery DataTables and onClick image in Header

Tags: jquery, datatables, html-table

I have a question mark inside the header of a table that uses JQuery Datatables. I tried disabling sorting (which isn't ideal) but the onclick event wont fire for my image.

Essentially DataTables hijacks the entire cell.

Does anybody know how I can get datatables to only use either text or a span within the cell so I can still have my question mark with its onclick event and also use DataTables for sorting?

I have this in the html head:

```
 $(function() {
    $('#dcsales').dataTable(
    {
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": false },
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    null,
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false }
    ]
    }
    );
});
```

I have this in the table header:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td><span id="qa_one"><img id="qa_one_t" src="img/question.png"/></span>Col 1</td>
<td> Col Two</td> ...
</tr>
</thead>
```

using firebug, I can see that DataTables inserts a class into the td. I would like to insert the generated class into a span with an certain class so maybe my header cells will look like this.

```
<td><span id="qa_one"><img id="qa_one_t" src="img/question.png"/></span><span class="datatables">Col 1</span></td>
```

I'm on their website reading the documentation and forum posts but can't find any relevant information.

---

### EDIT

Based on the following post
[Jquery datatable with checkbox in header and in row:select all checkbox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878989/jquery-datatable-with-checkbox-in-header-and-in-rowselect-all-checkbox-not-work)

which also led me to this
http://datatables.net/usage/columns

I changed the script in the head section to the following and everything from html:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dcsales').dataTable(
    {
    "aoColumns": [
    { "bSortable": false, "sTitle": "<span id='qa_one><img id='qa_one_t' src='img/question.png'/></span><span>Col One</span>", "mDataProp":null },
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    null,
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false }
    ]
    }
    );
});
```

It didn't make a difference though, the html markup is generated correctly but when I click on the image, the cursor clicks the entire cell.

Here is what the generated markup looks like after the changes:

```
<td class="sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 142px;" aria-label="Col One">
<span id="qa_points">
<span>Type of Points</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want but you use [this](http://datatables.net/ref#fnInitComplete)

#### Example JS :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    // you can use another callback if you want
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
      $("#qa_one_t").on('click',function(){
          alert('click fire on img !');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

## Note

in your js code you have :

`[...]<span id='qa_one><img id='qa_one_t'[...]`

missing `'` in order to have : `<span id='qa_one'>`

it could solve the problem. Is it helped you?

Comment: I actually have both single quotes in my code, not sure how it got removed. I'm going to read up on the link you posted and see if it helps.

Comment: It did not help, the problem is that DataTables hijacks the entire cell.

Comment: What do you mean by "hijacks the entire cell" ?